# How to match formatting of one cell in Google sheet with another?

Tags: google-sheets

I typed "2:30pm" into a cell in a Google sheet, and it formatted it as "2:30 PM". I typed "2:30pm" into a different cell, and it formatted it as "14:30".

**What I Want To Know:**

1. These were both cells in a new sheet and I hadn't typed anything into either of them before. Why might each get autoformatted differently?
2. I clicked on the "2:30 PM" one to try and see what format had been applied to it, in order to try and format the "14:30" one the same way. How do I tell what the current formatting on a cell is, such that I could apply the same formatting to other cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding point 1, there aren't enough details but even proving all the possible relevant details its very likely that only Google can answer it.

Regarding point 2, you don't need to see the formatting applied to a cell to apply it to another cell, use the **Paint format** tool.

[image]

Comment: That solves my problem, thanks! I hadn't heard of the paint format tool.